# Java split method Exclude specific letters

Tags: java

I am trying to split the Value using a separator.

```
String A = "[123,456,789,101]";
String[] array= A.split(",");

for(String s : array) {
    System.out.println(s);
    
}
```

### Out put :

[123

45

789

101]

How can take out the front and back letters [ , ] ?

Comment: `substring`, `replace`, `replaceAll`, there are plenty of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use this regex :

```
\\[|]
```

to replace the `outer most bracket` from your **string**.

```
String A = "[123,456,789,101]";
String[] array= A.replaceAll("\\[|]", "").split(",");

for(String s : array) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output :**

```
123
456
789
101
```

Answer (score 0):

We have different options to solve this.

**Option1:**

```
    String A = "[123,456,789,101]";
     A= A.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]",""); //In this case I am removing [ ] from a string.
    String[] array= A.split(",");
    
    for(String s : array) {
        System.out.println(s);
        
    }
```

**Option2:** Using StringUtils

```
String A = "[123,456,789,101]";
A =StringUtils.substringBetween(subject, "[", "]")
String[] array= A.split(",");
        
        for(String s : array) {
            System.out.println(s);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using regExp to remove '[' and ']'**

```
String A = "[123,456,789,101]";
String regExp = "\\[|\\]";
String[] array= A.replaceAll(regExp, "").split(",");
for(String s : array) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a genreic Regex, if you want to split on , and then replace all non number character, try this:
String A = "[123,456,789,101]";
String[] array= A.split(",");

```
    for(String s : array) {
        s = s.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""); // . will be retained
        System.out.println(s);
        
    }
```